# How to drive JOGL animation from my own thread

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, jogl

I'm using JOGL (jogamp) and want to drive the animation from my own thread. The tutorial I ran into shows using Animator or FPSAnimator, but those have their own threads and I want to avoid that.

This is because I'm doing various other thread management and such and so I already have a thread that knows when computation results are ready to push the next frame to the GPU.

Is this possible? Or is it just a really bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer is to directly call display on the GLWindow:

http://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.2/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/newt/opengl/GLWindow.html#display()